# Data not sending between classes - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, variables

I'm trying to send data between two classes. I've done it using the properties method, but the data keeps coming back on the other side empty.

**FrameGallery.h (class that's sending data):**

```
@interface FrameGallery{
    NSMutableArray *filesArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *filesArray;

@end
```

**FrameGallery.m**

```
#import "FrameGallery.h"

@implementation FrameGallery

@synthesize filesArray;
```

**LoadFilePopOverController.m (class that's receiving data)**

```
FrameGallery *frameGallery = [[FrameGallery alloc] init];   
NSLog(@"%@", frameGallery.filesArray);
```

Is there something that I'm missing here that's really obvious?

I've done it successfully in the past but I can't find the code where I used it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This comment is not valid. You can keep (in fact should keep) the ivar and the property as well.

Comment: On the other hand, this class is perfectly okay (besides the fact, that it doesn't have a dealloc) - but i don't see you your code that passes the data ... ?

Comment: <quote>I think you should remove NSMutableArray *filesArray; from @interface, and keep only the property.</quote>, I am sure his problem can be solved by still having it in the @interface. @Daniel, can you post what NSLog says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array in your LoadFilePopOverController and make it a property , synthesize it.

Now when you navigate to LoadFilePopOverController from FrameGallery , assign the array to the one that was created in LoadFilePopOverController.

For  e.g.

in LoadFilePopOverController.h

```
NSMutableArray *getdata;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *getdata;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize getdata;
```

Now in your FrameGallery.m , go to the code where you are performing your navigation,
and set the array like:

```
Loadvc.getdata = filesArray;
```