# Sending data between classes

Tags: objective-c

I seem to be missing a key fundamental concept on sending data between two classes. I read another post on here, and I'll comment on that in a sec, but here is what I have. In a custom view class, I got a NSMutableDictionary that is working fine and is retained:

```
@interface myView : UIView {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary*myDictionary;
```

The methods in myView use myDictionary with no problem. For example, I can do this fine:

```
 NSArray*sorted=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.myDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

In my view controller, I am then trying to create a similar array using the same data in the myDictionary object from the custom class:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet myView * myView;
```

Then later I have:

```
  NSArray*sorted=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.myView.myDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

However, this myDictionary is always empty. It is not released anywhere in myView so it should still contain data. I've tried removing "self" with no luck.

Now, I read this similar post:

[Data not sending between classes - Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185267/data-not-sending-between-classes-objective-c)

Is this the only method for doing something like this? This implies that you must "send" the data from the source class to the receiving class. It suggests that you cannot have the receiving class "go fetch" the data from the source class as I am here. Is that right? More importantly, if that is the only method, then why so?

Comment: Sounds like the IBOutlet is not hooked up. It's perfectly fine for one object to "fetch" something from another, as long as the first has a valid reference to the second.

Comment: The outlet is hooked up via the interface builder and displays fine, but I don't believe that should affect this particular issue since separately from the interface builder the myView class is made an ivar of the viewcontroller.

Comment: You're connecting the outlet in IB _and_ assigning to `myView` in code?

Comment: is the myView property actually set when you're in the myViewContoller? Try it out with a po [self myView] on the console in debug mode...

Comment: Hm... you might be onto something @JoshCaswell. I had been assigning it in code, as I wanted to control parameters like `hidden` and `frame` directly; they do not appear assignable unless you assign in code. How would I do so otherwise? by assigning in code, am I overriding this class with another instance of it?

Comment: suppose I want to send the data from the myView class to an array ivar in the view controller; what is the syntax for this? the view controller is technically the parent, so something along the lines of `self.viewcontroller.array=...` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly; the object in the xib is a real object. If you also assign to the outlet in code, you lose track of the object in the xib. Since there is a real view at the other end of the outlet, you _can_ change properties of that view using the outlet without creating a new view.

Comment: I am not allocating or initing in code, i'm just using @property for an outlet for the same custom view that is in my IB. This is fine, right? If I do not create an @property for myView in code, then I am unable to do things like self.myView.hidden=YES or manipulate self.myView.frame.

Comment: Oh, okay; yes, that is what you're supposed to do. You've verified that `myView` and `myView.myDictionary` are not `nil` when you try to access them from the controller?

Comment: indeed myView is coming up as nil, which makes no sense to me. It is certainly not nil when it draws on my screen, and I do not release it anywhere, so why would self.myView be nil when i reference it in code?

Comment: oh jeez. i found the issue. i'm sorry but i had failed at a very simple task of wiring up the IBOutlet in IB. It was set as an IBOutlet but not wired up. It was displaying, however, but probably because that custom view had its own instructions. But when it came from pulling data from it, I guess you cannot do this without the actual connection made from File owner in the IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triple-check your outlet connections! Then check them again.

When you hook up an `IBOutlet` through Interface Builder, you have a real, instantiated object at the other end. You can access the properties of that object just as you would with any other object:

```
self.myView.hidden = NO;
```

If you assign a new object to that outlet:

```
self.myView = [[MyCustomViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:someRect];
```

you lose track of the view that was created for you in the xib, and when you try to access ivars of that new view:

```
NSDictionary * aDict = self.myView.myDictionary;
```

they will not have the same values as the ivars of the other view that is in the xib (they will probably be `nil`, in fact).

It's perfectly all right for data to be passed in either direction. You just need to have the appropriate references. The view can "send" to the controller, but it needs to have a reference to that controller set up:

```
// Get a reference to view controller somehow
self.myController = ...;
[self.myController setArray:[self.myDictionary keys...]];
```

Since controllers generally have references to their views, it probably makes more sense to go the other way, as you're already doing.

Comment: In a side-note, I am curious how you would get a reference to a view's controller if you wanted to (which I don't).

Comment: Either set it up _from_ the controller -- In view: `@property (assign) UIViewController * myController;` In controller: `[self.myView setController:self]`, or just use an `IBOutlet`.